# Remote monitoring Windows print server queue

Tags: windows-server-2008, print-server

I would like to remotely monitor (and delete and/or reprint some jobs) the printing queues of a Windows print server, based on a Windows 2008 Server. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Update: the OS we will monitoring from is Windows 7/Vista/XP.

Comment: What OS are you going to be monitoring from?

Comment: From Windows also.

Comment: Seriously? I meant what version of Windows. The answer is going to be relevant to the version of Windows you're remotely managing from. Is it Windows 7, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2, etc., etc.?

Comment: From Windows 7, Vista and XP. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Windows Vista and 7 have access to the Print Management snap-in. This would allow you to remotely manage the print queue from the same network, but would require a VPN solution for management from away from the domain network.